# how to use geckodriver with watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I ran a `bundle update` yesterday night and `selenium-webdriver` got updated to the latest version.

My `watir-webdriver` tests pointed to `firefox` are now broken.

The error message said to add `geckodriver` to the path. On my mac, I copied `geckodriver` to the `/usr/bin` and ran the tests again.

This is the error I am getting now

`unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`

The `watir-webdriver` documentation does not seem to be updated on how to do this?

Did anyone manage to fix this

Comment: What versions of `watir-webdriver`, `selenium-webdriver`,`firefox` and `geckodriver` do you have?

Comment: `selenium-webdriver 3.0.0, watir-webdriver 0.9.3, geckodriver-v0.11.1`

Comment: And `firefox 49.0.2`?  You should post (in your original question) the minimal amount of code that reproduces the issue.  I'm unable to repro using the versions listed here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no extra documentation because there is nothing extra to do with Watir.  It's finding the geckodriver file , but can't run it. Check to make sure it is executable on your system.

Answer (score -1):

If your test not only just stick to firefox, you can use `chromedriver` instead of `geckodriver`, which is much easy, as far as my experience goes.

1,  Add gem `watir` to your gemfile.
2,  Download file on this page https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, and copy `chromedriver` to `/usr/bin` path.
3,   And then just run it:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.start(url)
html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
browser.close
```

4, Also, you can use `headless` to start a virtual X screen to hide browser windows like this:

```
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start

  browser = Watir::Browser.start(url)
  html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

  browser.close
  headless.destroy
```

Comment: I do not believe this answers the question. If the goal is to test Firefox, switching to Chrome does not solve the problem.